# If then statement issue

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

[image: Example]

Hi guys, I'm trying to learn Python. I'm trying to mess around with printing and if then statements. For some reason, whatever number I type in the first box says "I am not 12" (even if I type the number 12. Also, for the second statement, no matter what I put, it will say I am correct. Any help is suggested.

Comment: This isn't a huge issue, I'm just trying to learn/mess around a little in Python while I'm working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hey there, please post source code by as text, rather than as screenshots.

Comment: the `input()` is returning a string, so your `NUM` / `NUM2` will always be different from the number you're comparing to

Comment: NUM = input("Enter your number: ")
if NUM == 12:
    print("I am 12")
elif NUM != 12:
 print("I am not 12")
NUM2 = input("Enter your second number: ")
if NUM2 ==55:
    print("This is not the correct number")
elif NUM2 !=55:
 print("You are correct")

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is with your input.
when you enter the number 12 it is not returned as a number. it is returned as a string.

If you want to compare your input to the number 12 you need to convert it to a number.

```py
NUM = int(input("enter your number: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` takes in a string. You then compare the string against an integer, which will always return `False`.

To resolve, use `int(input())` rather than just `input()`. (Note that this will break against non-numeric characters.)